# ExtJs 4.1 Callback scope again

Tags: extjs, callback, scope, extjs4.1

How can I keep `this` when calling my callback function?

```
init: function() {

 console.log( this ); // constructor, YES!

 this.readConfig();
},

readConfig: function() {

 console.log( this ); // constructor, YES!

 this.httpApi.request({
    module   : 'monitor',
    func     : 'getConfig',
    success  : this.readConfigCallback,
    scope    : this
 });
},

readConfigCallback: function(oResponse) {

 console.log( this ); // Window, NO!

 var oView = this.getView(); // error...
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ...

```
success: Ext.bind(this.readConfigCallback, this)
```

... instead to bind the object's context to the callback function specifically. Otherwise this function will be called in the global context, and its `this` function will refer to `window`.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Will use in the future.